# How to load ion-image in ngSwitchCase?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

when i to use **ion-img** in **ngSwitchCase** , the image get **img-unloaded** class.

```
<ion-img class="img-unloaded" ng-reflect-src="../../assets/imgs/avatar.png"><img></ion-img>
```

i use **ionic 3.9.2v**

Comment: Can you give more information please? Maybe you can control your switch-case cases.

Comment: when i use ion-img in  **segment** , ion-img not working . beacuse ion-img is only meant to be used inside of virtual-scroll.

Comment: You can use ion-icon or normal img instead of ion-img.